# Is it possible to add operators into manchester syntax?

Tags: sparql, owl, protege

I want to add custom operators for temporal representation kind of like how this paper describes on page 8: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c097/3553764e2959af3ad4513515588791a13867.pdf.

Although it can be done in SPARQL, (I'm assuming through use of registries like this -> https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/DeveloperGuide-SPARQL-Operators) I would like to know if it also possible to add these same operators into manchester syntax or find an alternative way of doing things so that I can do a temporal query within a DL Query.

Comment: how should this be possible? manchester syntax is just one way of serializing OWL DL ontologies, thus, extending the underlying Description Logic by features clearly also needs for adapting the whole semantics and also the reasoning procedure.